# JSON isinstance decoder is only decoding the strings to numbers, but not dates

Tags: python, json, datetime, jsondecoder, encoder-decoder

I have a JSON file that has dates and integers in them. All of them are showing as strings. I used a JSON decoder to get the strings parsed into integers, but I am having issues getting the date strings into actual date format. My JSON file is below:

```
{"Time Open": "71", "Name": "John Doe", "Date Closed": "", "Date Created": "4/11/2021", "Due Date": "5/29/2021", "TimeStamp": "08/09/2021 00:00:00 AM"}
```

So far I used the "isinstance" to parse the Time Open strings into integers, but the "isinstance" isn't working for changing the dates "4/11/2021" to "2021-04-11" Seems like its not detecting my datetime.datetime "isinstance". Any help will be appreciated. I have my code below.

```
from datetime import datetime

class Decoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    def decode(self, s):
        result = super().decode(s)  # result = super(Decoder, self).decode(s) for Python 2.x
        return self._decode(result)
    
    def _decode(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, str):
            try:
                return int(o)
            except ValueError:
                return o
        elif isinstance(o, datetime):
            try:
                return datetime.datetime.strptime(o, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            except ValueError:
                return o
        elif isinstance(o, dict):
            return {k: self._decode(v) for k, v in o.items()}
        elif isinstance(o, list):
            return [self._decode(v) for v in o]
        else:
            return o
```

I'm using json.loads to go to this Decoder class as below:

```
json_doc = json.loads(doc, cls=Decoder)
```

Comment: You almost have it, the code is very close to working.  Just have a think about when the `elif isinstance(o, datetime):` branch of the logic would ever be entered.

Comment: Dates are.not json types. You will need to, perhaps, search for particular keys and replace the string values with their conversion to a date type.

Comment: *"Seems like its not detecting my datetime.datetime "isinstance""* — Yeah, 'cause it's a string.

Comment: since you import the datetime class from the datetime module, use `return datetime.strptime(o, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I removed the datetime with datetime.strptime, but it's still not working. Any other suggestions. @FObersteiner

Comment: Well… more hints: you're trying to convert numbers by trying to parse the string as an `int`, and catching errors when that fails. … Your dates are Also. Just. Strings!